# AngularJS won't run controller unless refreshed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Really simple (code below). I have two html pages, test.htm and ang.htm. I start on test.htm with a single hyperlink to the ang.htm page. The ang.htm contains angular js that has one simple controller that does a Hello World. I click on the hyperlink to navigate to ang.htm. However I need to refresh the ang.htm page in order for the angular code to run. Why is that?

> **test.htm**

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://localhost/ang.htm">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

> **ang.htm**

```
<html>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
    {{hello}}

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        angular.module("testApp", []);

        angular.module( "testApp" ).controller( "testController", function( $scope )
        {
            $scope.hello = "Hello world";
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yep, it works. btw, better move scripts to head

Comment: No moving scripts to <head> doesn't work either. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only changed ***localhost/ang.htm*** to ***/ang.htm*** in according to file structure. It works as expected.

Debugging with Firebug would be very helpful in your case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/ang.htm">Click</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that the problem is the AngularJS Batarang extension in Chrome. Looks like they recently upgraded it with a hint.js file that has been causing problems with other devs. I just disabled it and everything works just fine. I feel like you put me in the right direction by suggesting I try Firefox instead. Once it worked there I knew the problem was with Chrome and the hints.js stuff I recently started seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, fiddle is talking: http://jsfiddle.net/m7beqvaf/

The `{{hello}}` token may not be replaced as soon as the page shows up loaded but that's all. Navigating to `ang.htm` can't be a problem.

Note that I copy/pasted your `ang.htm` content in the fiddle:

```
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
    {{hello}}

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        angular.module("testApp", []);

        angular.module( "testApp" ).controller( "testController", function( $scope )
        {
            $scope.hello = "Hello world";
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well it does work in jsfiddle because you are in a new browser tab. Staying within the same browser tab when you navigate for some odd reason doesn't allow angular to bootstrap correctly. I've tried manually bootstrapping but that failed too. Mystery.

Comment: Well the code you posted is correct. However, maybe you can provide us the whole `ang.htm` file's content in case you haven't.

Comment: That's all there is, it's that simple. But in this case it can't be repeated in jsfiddle since it involves two htm files. Just drop these two files on your web server and try and run them, you'll see what I'm talking about. All I can guess is that angular isn't running because the navigation event wasn't being handled by angular and therefore it's not trying to run a scope digest or something.